# How to get php-fpm to log to stdout / stderr when running in a docker container

Tags: logging, php-fpm, best-practices, docker

I have php-fpm in a docker container and in the `Dockerfile` I edit the fpm config file (`/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`) to set up access logs to go to `/var/log/fpm-access.log` and error logs to go to `/var/log/fpm-php.www.log`:

```
# Do some php-fpm config
#  Redirect worker stdout and stderr into main error log
#  Activate the fpm access log
#  Enable display errors
#  Enable the error log
RUN sed -i '/^;catch_workers_output/ccatch_workers_output = yes' /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf && \
    sed -i '/^;access.log/caccess.log = /var/log/fpm-access.log' /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf && \
    sed -i '/^;php_flag\[display_errors\]/cphp_flag[display_errors] = off' /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf && \
    sed -i '/^;php_admin_value\[error_log\]/cphp_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log' /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf && \
    sed -i '/^;php_admin_flag\[log_errors\]/cphp_admin_flag[log_errors] = on' /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

This works fine - I can get a shell into the container to see the logs. But... it is not best-practice.

The problem is when I try to use the *docker log collector* - I need php-fpm to log to stdout or stderr so docker can capture them and provide them to the `docker logs` command.

I tried to do this in the `Dockerfile` (which is a idea I copied from the [official nginx docker image](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/57da11369acbec3256b0c2704a50282eeabb684f/Dockerfile#L13)):

```
# Redirect fpm logs to stdout and stderr so they are forwarded to the docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/fpm-access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
```

This is not working - no access logs are seen from `docker logs` - I'm trying to figure out why? Did anyone else that uses fpm in docker manage to get logging working to the docker log collector?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ok, the way to do this is to send the error and the access logs to the following address:

```
/proc/self/fd/2
```

In `php5-fpm.conf` (or the appropriate configuration file) add:

```
access.log = /proc/self/fd/2
error_log = /proc/self/fd/2
```

NOTE: `access.log` is correct, find in this page https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php

Comment: It's possible for there to be `/dev/stdin ~ /dev/fd/0 ~ /proc/self/fd/0`, and `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` variants. Might be easier to remember to use `/dev/stdin`.

Comment: There's an error in the answer - it's "access_log" not "access.log"

Comment: It appears that it is `access.log`: https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/6e600f59a4405b5066eb78f5f02180212dffd065/5.6/fpm/php-fpm.conf

Comment: Believe this should be `php5-fpm.conf`, or on a more current PHP, `php-fpm.conf`. Adding those directives to `.log` file would do nothing :D

Answer (score 20):

Note that the baked in [fpm config](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/6e600f59a4405b5066eb78f5f02180212dffd065/5.6/fpm/php-fpm.conf) for the latest version of the official [PHP fpm docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) writes to the standard streams:

```
error_log = /proc/self/fd/2

...

; if we send this to /proc/self/fd/1, it never appears
access.log = /proc/self/fd/2
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. I didn't know that there's a official image now

Comment: Which docker image are you referring to?  I ran php:7-fpm and it doesn't appear to be logging errors to `stderr`.

Comment: If you run `php-fpm` inside a container it should report what `error_log` value is. In my case it's `/proc/self/fd/2` as needed. Docker image `php:7.2-fpm`.

Comment: @laimison "Report" `error_log` where?

Answer (score 2):

PHP-FPM logs will only appear in STDERR - so you can symlink the `fpm.log` to `/dev/stderr` if you want.

```
ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/fpm-access.log
ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/fpm-error.log
```

Comment: This solution was given in the question and the asker stated it didn't work. Maybe you can specify how he can load it in his dockerfile to make it work properly or other diagnostics he can perform on his container?

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek file names are different